# How to add broadcastable tensor with given values to another tensor in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

```
def get_output_for(self, input, **kwargs):
    bias=self._srng.uniform(input.shape)
    output=input+bias
    return theano.tensor.clip(output,0,1)
```

I'm trying to create a custom layer in Theano/Lasagne, which shifts the image matrix for some random bias. I want this bias to be a constant for a certain image, but different for every another image in a batch.

'input' is a tensor with shape ('x',3,32,32),where 'x' is broadcastable dimension, representing image batch count. The code above adds a ('x',3,32,32) matrix of random numbers to 'input'.
However, I want the number to be the same for every image (bias[i,:,:,:]=const)
and random only among different images (bias[i,:]!=bias[j,:])
The problem is that I cannot access directly to the broadcastable dimension.
Any ideas on how can I do this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested but you can create a vector of random numbers whose size equals the batch size and then add broadcastable dimensions using `dimshuffle`:

```
bias=self._srng.uniform(input.shape[0]).dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x', 'x')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

bias=self._srng.uniform((input.shape[0],1,1,1)).dimshuffle(0, 'x', 'x', 'x')